# Read chars from file c++

Tags: c++

I have a file with this format:

```
# This is one comment
# Another comment
```

But the problem is that when running the following code:

```
    char c;
    string string1;
    while ((c = fgetc(file))  == '#') {
        string1 += c;
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n') {
            string1 += c;
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
# This is one comment# Another comment
```

I know that in the second while the '\n' in the first comment is not saved in the string1, but how can I solve it with this approach or similar?

Comment: Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: that code has no output, nor is it entirely clear what you want the output to be.

Comment: @EduardoLeón - `getline` will also swallow the newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
char c;
string string1;
while ((c = fgetc(file))  == '#') {
    string1 += c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n') {
        string1 += c;
    }
    string1 += c;
}
```

Because after the program goes out the second loop, **c**'s value is '\n', you can just put it in your **string1**

This is my test .cpp file and you can try it out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char c;
    string string1;
    FILE * file = fopen("test.in","r");

    while ((c = fgetc(file))  == '#') {
        string1 += c;
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != '\n') {
            string1 += c;
        }
        string1 += c;
    }
    cout<<string1<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And "test.in" is the text you wanna input.

Thanks.